# get specific data from https body

Tags: node.js

I want to get the median_price value from [link](https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&market_hash_name=M4A1-S%20%7C%20Decimator%20(Field-Tested)&median_price)

My code:

```
const https = require('https');
var item = ('M4A1-S | Decimator (Field-Tested)')
var body = '';
https.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&market_hash_name=' + item, res => {
    res.on('data', data => {
        body += data;})
    res.on('end', () => console.log(body));
}).on('error', error => console.error(error.message));
```

output is:

```
{"success":true,"lowest_price":"$5.17","volume":"469","median_price":"$5.09"}
```

I want it to be:

```
5.09
```

so I can add multiple values together. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the result into javascript object using `JSON.parse`, access it as usual and turn it to number using `parseFloat` (you can use `substr` method to remove the leading `$`)

```
parseFloat(JSON.parse(body).median_price.substr(1))
```

so in your code

```
res.on('end', () => console.log(parseFloat(JSON.parse(body).median_price.substr(1)));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Such a simple and clean answer!